# Access files relative to imported python module

Tags: python, import, relative-path, python-import

Preliminary:

I have Anaconda 3 on Windows 10, and a folder, `folder_default`, that I have put on the Python path. I'm not actually sure whether that's the right terminology, so to be clear: regardless to where my Python script is, if I have a line of code that says `import myFile`, that line of code will succeed if `myFile.py` is in `folder_default`.

My issue:

In `folder_default`, I have:

1. A subfolder called `useful_files` which contains a text file called `useful_file_1.txt`.
2. A python script called `my_misc.py`.

`my_misc.py` has a line similar to: `np.loadtxt('useful_files/useful_file_1.txt')`. This line does not work if I use `import my_script` in a python file in a location other than `folder_default`, since `useful_files/useful_file_1.txt` is not the folder path relative to the python file that imports `my_misc.py`. I don't want to start using global file paths if I can avoid it.

How can I access files using file paths relative to the imported python module, rather than relative to the python script that imports that module?

Please let me know if the question is unclear - I tried to write a fake, minimal version of the setup that's actually on my computer in the hopes that that would simplify things, but I can change it if that actually makes things more confusing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the path to current module using the `getfile` method of `inspect` module as `inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())`.
For example:

```
# File : my_misc.py
import os, inspect

module_dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe()))) # get path to the directory of current module
useful_file_path = os.path.join(module_dir_path,'useful_files','useful_file_1.txt')
# path stored in useful_file_path. do whatever you want!

np.loadtxt(useful_file_path)
```